# How do I split an ssrs text value by comma?

Tags: vba, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I have an SSRS report that takes a parameter called Customer ID Enroller List. Its datatype in SSMS is varchar(max) and its datatype in SSDT/SSRS is listed as text.

As an example, the user may pass in 2 customerID's like the following:

```
2110012639,2110179997
```

I'd like to create document map based the passed parameters but I need to split the values first. I've tried using the following code:

```
=Split(Parameters!CustomerID_EnrollerList.Value,",")
```

My report runs but the value returned in the textbox is #Error. Any ideas on how to split a text datatype parameter by a comma delimiter?

Comment: Does it have to be split in the SSRS code? Could it be a parameter to the TSQL and you use a string splitting or delimited string to table type function to use the values there? That's what we did with a lot of our CSV variables - just passed them into a varchar(max) and passed through to SQL to parse out.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot how the report would be rendered if it worked?

Comment: @Peter Schott - your recommendation worked as my actual solution. It handles the variable entry by users perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Split function returns an array and you can select item by its index

First value would be
`=Split(Parameters!CustomerID_EnrollerList.Value,",")(0)`

And Second value would be
`=Split(Parameters!CustomerID_EnrollerList.Value,",")(1)`

Comment: Gotcha, What if the number of ID's passed is variable though? I passed 2 as an example but the number will vary.